# Using this to select different classes inside various classes with the same names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make different links using the same jQuery script for each of them. Instead of writing jQuery script for each of the links I would like to make it using only one function.

My HTML structure is:

```
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red"></div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here I have two links using the same class for click selector, and inside each of them have different classes inside div's

The jQuery script so far is:

```
$( ".link-chart", this).click(function($e) {
    if($(this).find(".link-selector-two").hasClass('red')) {              
        $('.link-selector-two').addClass('cssclass');           
        $('.link-selector-one').addClass('cssclass');  
    } else {
        $('.link-selector-two').removeClass('cssclass');
    }   
});
```

I was trying to use (this) but in the current state it is not working. The goal is if I click the first link to change the styles only for the first link div's which are wrapped inside the `<a>` link. If I select the second one the changes to be made only for the second one. Right now I remove the this option it If I click any of them it is making the changes on all of the links but the idea is to make the change only on the selected link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `$( ".link-chart", this)` doesn't do what you think it does.  Since you are in the global scope and *not* in a function, `this` is just `window` and therefore not needed here.

You should just use `$( ".link-chart", this).click(function($e) {});`.

Second, inside this click handler, `this` will be the `<a>` tag you clicked on.  From there you can get just the child elements you want.

```
$( ".link-chart").click(function($e) {
    if($(this).find(".link-selector-two").hasClass('red')) {              
        $('.link-selector-two', this).addClass('cssclass');           
        $('.link-selector-one', this).addClass('cssclass');  
    } else {
        $('.link-selector-two', this).removeClass('cssclass');
    }   
});
```

NOTE: `$('.link-selector-two', this)` is shorthand for `$(this).find('.link-selector-two')`.

Comment: You can group your selectors using: `$('.link-selector-one, .link-selector-two', this).addClass('cssclass');`

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation and problem solving.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `this` from `$( ".link-chart", this)` and adding `this` to your selectors `$('.link-selector-two')` and `$('.link-selector-one')` inside the click function will affect items within each `link-chart`

Run the code snippet below to see it in action

```js
$(".link-chart").click(function($e) {
    if($(this).find(".link-selector-two").hasClass('red')) {
          $('.link-selector-two', this).addClass('cssclass');
          $('.link-selector-one', this).addClass('cssclass');
    } else {
      $('.link-selector-two', this).removeClass('cssclass');
    }
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }

.cssclass { color: blue !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red">One</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red">Two</div>
  </div>
</a>
```